# Normals to a cube seem to be pointing inwards

Tags: c++, opengl, normals

I have written the following function to draw a cube:

```
void drawCube() {

   Point vertices[8] = { Point(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0), Point(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, -1.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, -1.0, -1.0),
                         Point(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0), Point(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, 1.0, -1.0) };

   int faces[6][4] = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 7, 4}, {0, 1, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {3, 2, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7}};

   glBegin(GL_QUADS);

   for (unsigned int face = 0; face < 6; face++) {

     Vector v = vertices[faces[face][1]] - vertices[faces[face][0]];
     Vector w = vertices[faces[face][2]] - vertices[faces[face][0]];

     Vector normal = v.cross(w).normalised();

     glNormal3f(normal.dx, normal.dy, normal.dz);

     for (unsigned int vertex = 0; vertex < 4; vertex++) {

       switch (vertex) {
         case 0: glTexCoord2f(0, 0); break;
         case 1: glTexCoord2f(1, 0); break;
         case 2: glTexCoord2f(1, 1); break;
         case 3: glTexCoord2f(0, 1); break;
       }

       glVertex3f(vertices[faces[face][vertex]].x, vertices[faces[face][vertex]].y, vertices[faces[face][vertex]].z);
     }
   }

   glEnd();
}
```

When the cube is rendered with a light shining on to it, it appears that as I rotate the cube, the correct shading transitions are only happening for around half the faces. The rest just remain a very dark shade, as if I had removed the normal calculations.

I then decided to remove a couple of faces to see inside the cube. The faces that are not reflecting the light correctly on the outside, are doing so correctly on the inside. How can I ensure that the normal to each face is pointing out from that face, rather than in towards the centre of the cube?

Comment: if you know the center of the cube you can easily check if the normal is pointing away from it

Comment: Could I just check that the distance from the centre to the (x, y, z) of the normal vector is greater than the distance from the centre to the point that the normal was calculated from? If not, then set `normal = -normal`?

Comment: sorry my comment was partly wrong and misleading, i will write an answer in a seond

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the direction of the normal, swap the order you use for the cross product:

```
Vector normal = w.cross(v).normalised();
```

Comment: But, only some of the normals are pointing imwards, how can I check if a normal is pointing inwards? If it is, then I can do what you have mentioned above

Comment: @KOB You'll need to change to order of vertices in some of your faces, so that all the faces have the verts go in the same order (clockwise or counter-clockwise) when you look at them.  Your system needs to have a consistent _handedness_ (right handed or left handed).

Comment: the handedness to how my faces are rendered was the source of the entire problem - correcting this fixed everything.

Comment: read your answer, misunderstood it, wrote mine, realized that yours is the solution and mine is ...*facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more efficient way, but a imho quite easy to understand way is the following....

Calculate the vector that points from the center of the side to the center of the cube. Call it

```
m = center cube - center side
```

Then calculate the scalar product of that vector with your normal:

```
x = < m , n >
```

The scalar product is positive if the two vectors point in the same direction with respect to the side (the angle between them is less than 90 degree). It is negative, if they point in opposite directions (angle is bigger than 90 degree). Then correct your normal via

```
if ( x > 0 ) n = -n;
```

to make sure it always points outwards.